# My code will not output the correct item number

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a section of my code: In the first section below, I have declared a bunch of floats and integers. I've already fstreamed an input file that has three columns of data. Each line item represents a shape. A rectangle, a triangle or a circle. I have successfully determined which items are which. Below I'm trying to take that data and compute the area of each shape. for circle, pi*r^2, for rectangle, Length*Width, for equilateral triangle, 1/2L*H. SO, then I take the max area for each shape type and put them in a loop with conditionals. I can successfully get the correct max area of all three shapes but I can't get the code to output the correct item number. Can you help?

```
// 3. Which block has the largest area?
// ........................................................

float RA[M];
float CA[M];
float TA[M];
float MRA = 0.0;
float MCA = 0.0;
float MTA = 0.0;
int ItmR = 0;
int ItmC = 0;
int ItmT = 0;
int ItmN = 0;

// ........................................................

for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
  if (btype[i] == Rectangles)
  {
    RA[i] = D[i] * E[i];

    if (MRA < RA[i])
    {
      MRA = RA[i];
      ItmR = i+1;
    }
  }
//}
//cout << "The block with the largest area is " << ItmR
//     << endl;

// ........................................................

//for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
//{
if (btype[i] == Circles)
{
  CA[i] = (3.14 * (D[i] * D[i]));

  if (MCA < CA[i])
  {
    MCA = CA[i];
    ItmC = i+1;
  }
}
//}
//cout << "MCA = " << MCA << ", Item No. " << ItmC
//     << endl;

// ........................................................

//for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
//{
if (btype[i] == Triangles)
{
  TA[i] = (0.5 * (D[i] * E[i]));

  if (MTA < TA[i])
  {
    MTA = TA[i];
    ItmT = i+1;
  }
}
//}
//cout << "MTA = " << MTA << ", Item No. " << ItmT
//     << endl;

// ........................................................

if (MRA < MCA)
{
  MRA = MCA;
  ItmN = ItmC;
}
else
  if (MRA < MTA)
  {
    MRA = MTA;
    ItmN = ItmT;
  }
  else
  {
    MRA = MRA;
    ItmN = ItmR;
  }
}
cout << MRA << " " << ItmN << endl;
```

I can't figure out how to get it to output the correct item number for the answer. The code definitely outputs the correct area but the ItmN (item number) is wrong.

Comment: I edited your post to remove the backticks from the code block, they are not needed in there.

Comment: What item number do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger (like e.g. `gdb` on Linux), and compile your code with all warnings enabled (with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux).

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, I am trying to get the program to output a char character that corresponds to the line number of the item in the array. So far I have gotten the algorithm to find the correct maximum area from my Blocks file and output the correct item number. I don't know how to change the item number to a char letter. I would like to have A=1 B=2 and so on. I tried to declare the ItmC, T, R, N as char variables. I declared them as char and assigned them to 'A' because I thought that would be like setting an int to 0. This did not work so I'm stumped. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot even get the maximum area, as if `MRA` is less than `MCA` and `MCA` is less then `MTA`, the output will be the area of `MCA`, as the neither of the two `else` part will get executed.

For clearness, you should also define a separate variable to represent the maximum area, instead of reusing `MRA`, and the final segment of judging the maximum area should be put outside the whole `for` loop, not inside.

```
float maxA = MRA;
ItmN = ItmR;
if (maxA < MCA)
{
    maxA = MCA;
    ItmN = ItmC;
}
//else
if (maxA < MTA)
{
    maxA = MTA;
    ItmN = ItmT;
}
//else
//{
//     maxA = MRA;
//     ItmN = ItmR;
//}

cout << maxA << " " << ItmN << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about finding the max area. I fixed that part of my algorithm but it still will not output an item number (ItmN).

Comment: I am trying to get it to output a char value for the item number. I initialized all the ItmR, C, T, N as char variables starting at 'A' and i left the above algorithm alone. Why won't this work?

Comment: You may have to give the current code, as I cannot guess where you've edited your code. But I think you can still use this code, and use `cout << (char)('A' + ItemN) << endl;` to output, if you are sure you have less than 26 items. And what do you mean by "will not output an item number"?

Comment: I meant the code will not output a char character, sorry. It outputs an item number fine. Everything works fine except for this char business. I'll try cout << (char)('A' + ItmN) << endl; THanks for you help.